# Why doesn't Ronon's gun run out of power?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

As far as I know, we have never seen Ronon's gun run of of power in SGA.
However, in episode 5 of Season 4 (Travelers), when Sheppard is using a similar gun, it runs out of power after several shots.

So what prevents Ronon's gun from running out of power? If it does, how does he recharge/reload it?

Comment: Sheppard uses a gun a couple of centuries out of date.   Ronon's gun is likely a newer model and more power efficient.

Comment: @cde I've seen fan theories saying  that but nothing from the showrunners about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a replaceable - some say rechargeable - power cell. You can see a spare on Ronon's belt in many shots, but there is as far as I can recall only one time you see him actually replace the power cell. In the tavern scene near the beginning of S2E7 "Instinct," he replaces the cell near the end of the conversation, just before he stands up.

In S4E5 "Travelers" at about the 26 minute mark, you see Shepard ask Larrin if she has more "of these," referring to either the weapon, or the power cell he removes from the depleted gun. They are both weaponless because the gun is out of power.

The show never actually shows how he replaces/recharges the cells, though. Probably for the same reason they never show the SG teams loading ammo into magazines. :)

Comment: Well, they don't show them loading bullets into a clip, but they do show them changing clips at some points (this is my last clip sir). But the meaning is clear

Comment: Which is what he said. "Magazine" (or even more specific "removable box magazine") is the proper term for what laymen call a "clip" (which is actually something used to fill certain types of magazines).